# SQL Server 2012 -Union into temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have 2 Tables

```
Table:#Temp1 [1 row]
select ID from #Temp1
result: 1

Table:#Temp2 [1 row]
select ID from #Temp2
result: 1

select ID from #Temp1 
union 
select ID from #Temp2
result: 1
```

But.

```
select ID into #Temp3 from #Temp1 
union 
select ID from #Temp2
result: insert 2 rows
```

[Why select is a row, insert is two rows?]

thanks.

Comment: can you show us what was in #Temp1 and #Temp2 ?

Comment: the possible reason you get 1 row from the `SELECT .. UNION` is both #Temp1 & #Temp2 having the same ID value. `UNION` eliminates duplicate value. So your `INSERT` should be 1 row also unless you are using `UNION ALL`

Comment: Shan, your query should not be inserting 2 rows. I suspect you've done something slightly different that you haven't mentioned. If you try the script in my answer as-is, you should observe the 1 row inserted.

Comment: I tried this but only 1 record is inserted in #Temp3. Do you already have a record with Id = 1 in #Temp3. ?

Comment: @PawanKumar `select ... into #temp3` won't work if `#temp3` already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your claim is incorrect.

See the following example and output from SQL Server 2016 SP1.

```
select 1 as id into #t1
select 1 as id into #t2

print ''
print 'select t1 union t2'
print '------------------'
select id from #t1
union
select id from #t2

print ''
print 'select into t3'
print '--------------'

select id into #t3 from #t1
union
select id from #t2

print ''
print 'select from t3'
print '--------------'
select id from #t3

drop table #t1
drop table #t2
drop table #t3
```

Output

```
(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

select t1 union t2
------------------
id
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)


select into t3
--------------

(1 row(s) affected)

select from t3
--------------
id
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

You'll see that select into `#t3` is 1 row affected, and select from the table also returns only 1 row.

---

What you may be experiencing is the fact that `union` removes duplicates. So if both rows from `#t1` and `#t2` have the same values, then union returns only 1 row. However, if in a different test you have different values then each unique row will be returned.

Note that `union` has an optional `all` qualifier. So,

```
select ...
union all
select ...
```

would not remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert the union, try the insert after the union

```
Select Id into #temp3
From
(
Select ID from #Temp1 union select ID from #Temp2
)
```

This will allow the union to take place prior to the insert, which will allow ids from table 1 and 2 that match to union together producing a single record if I'd is in both

Comment: This is incorrect. What you propose is not needed. OP is somehow mistaken about the behaviour but failed to provide enough detail. Take a look at my answer to see a full [mcve] demonstrating the actual behaviour.